# Call to a member function create() on a non-object Laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, image-uploading

Im a beginner in Laravel. I have two login authentication types; using facebook API and using your own email.
Everytime I upload an image when im logging in with my own email, I got this error

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Call to a member function create() on a non-object","file":"C:\base_app_folder\app\controllers\OnboardingController.php","line":133}}

But it's success uploading image when im logging in with Facebook API

Here's my Controller :

```
if (Input::hasFile('profile_pic')) {
        $images = ImageUpload::handle(Input::file('profile_pic'));
        $mainImage = $images[0];
        $time = time();
        $mainImageObj = $this->images->create($this->userId, array(
            'entity_id' => $this->currentUser->Entity_Id,
            'image_url' => $mainImage['image_url'],
            'width' => $mainImage['width'],
            'height' => $mainImage['height'],
            'created_fb' => $time,
            'is_original' => $mainImage['is_original'],
            'original_id' => null
        ));

        $this->userDetails->update($this->userId, array(
            'Profile_Pic_Url' => $mainImageObj->image_url
        ));

        array_shift($images);

        Log::info('images = '.print_r($images, true));
        $retImage = "";
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $this->images->create($this->userId, array(
                'entity_id' => $this->currentUser->Entity_Id,
                'image_url' => $image['image_url'],
                'width' => $image['width'],
                'height' => $image['height'],
                'created_fb' => $time,
                'is_original' => $image['is_original'],
                'original_id' => $mainImageObj->image_id
            ));
            if ($image['width'] == 250) {
                $retImage = $image['image_url'];
            }
        }

        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Upload succeeded!',
            'image_thumbnail_url' => $retImage,
            'image_url' => $mainImage['image_url']
        ));
    } else {
        App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

Here's my View :

```
<form action="{{{ route('postEditProfile', array('profile_id' => Session::get('user_id'))) }}}" class="dropzone" id="profile-pic-upload">
                        <div class="fallback">
                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And here's the javascirpt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {
var pic_height = $('.profile_pic').height();
var pic_width = $('.profile_pic').width();
var height_factor = pic_height/240;
var pic_width = pic_width/height_factor;
$('.profile_pic').css('height','240px');
$('.profile_pic').css('width',pic_width+"px");
});
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    });

    var routes = {
        postEditProfile: "{{{ route('postOnboardingPhotos') }}}"
    };

    var onboarding = new Onboarding(routes);
});
</script>
```

Anyone knows how to solve it ? I've searching for the error message but it seems no one ever found this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to inject a dependency and assign `$this->images` to that dependency? Looks like you have an images repository and you forgot to take care of this.